# Jasmine unit test on Angular $timeout method

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have the following controller in my Angular application.

```
m = angular.module "myapp.dashboards"

    m.directive "lkDashboardElement", (
      $timeout
      MyAppSettings
    )->

      scope:
        dashboard: "="
        element: "="
        dashboardController: "="
        elementLoaded: "&"

      link: ($scope, $el)->

        if MyAppSettings.shouldCalculateTableWidth

          document.addEventListener "dashboard.element.rendered", =>

            $timeout(->
              ..
              ..
            )
```

I remove a lot of stuff so only the important part shows. The thing that I am having trouble with has to do with my usage of the Angular [$timeout](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout). I am currently checking for a certain condition `shouldCalculateTableWidth`, and if I see an event fire, I immediately timeout.

Currently I am trying to write a unit test that checks whether `$timeout` is being used.

Here is my test:

```
describe "in a phantomjs context", ->
  beforeEach ->
    # This sets our Phantom rendering context to true for testing purposes
    MyAppSettings._setIsPhantomRendering(true)

  afterEach ->
    MyAppSettings._setIsPhantomRendering(false)

  it "uses $timeout (instead of applyAsync) for adjusting table widths", ->
    # Creates a dummy dashboard
    dashboardController.queryMap = {1: {view: "foo", model: "bar"}}
    dashboard.elements = [{id: 1}]
    spyOn($timeout, "flush")
    expect($timeout.flush).toHaveBeenCalled()
```

What I am trying to do is simply test whether `$timeout` is being used in this piece of code, since it is important to how certain images are rendered when I am in Phantom (an image rendering library) context. When I run the test, I get the following error:

```
Expected spy flush to have been called.
```

The specific issue I have is the following two lines in my test:

```
spyOn($timeout, "flush")
expect($timeout.flush).toHaveBeenCalled()
```

First of all, I don't believe I am calling the right method for `$timeout`. It's very clear in my controller, I am calling `$timeout`, and not `$timeout.flush`. Second of all, for Jasmine Spys, you can't just `spyOn` the `$timeout`, since it needs both a reference to a class and a method.

So I am not quite sure how to move on. I would appreciate any help - thanks!

Comment: `flush` is a method that only exists in `ngMock`, to be called from tests. So spying on flush only checks to see that you called it from the test. It's your test, you know you did/didn't, so why would you want to check it?

Answer (score 1):

When you are writing the unit test, you have to call `$timeout.flush()` and then call `$timeout.verifyNoPendingTasks();`.

`verifyNoPendingTasks()` will throw an exception if there are any pending timeouts, so basically, you can assert that the exception is never thrown like `expect(function () {$timeout.verifyNoPendingTasks()}).not.toThrow()`. Also, you can write the expectation as `expect(function () {$timeout.flush()}).toThrow()`

If in your controller `$timeout` has a fixed time like `$timeout(function() {}, 1000)`, then in your unit test you can `flush` as `$timeout.flush(1000)`.

You can read more at [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$timeout).

Also, you can take a look at the following [CodePen](http://codepen.io/gauravmahto/pen/Wpevgv?editors=1010) for the working example.

Comment: Hey thanks Gaurav! Would I need to spy on anything? Or I assume call `$timeout.flush()`, then check the expects?

Comment: When you call `$timeout.flush()`, it clears all the `$timeout()` that means in your test, you can write the assertion something like `expect(function() {$timeout.verifyNoPendingTasks()}).not.toThrow()`.

Comment: And No, you don't need to spy on anything as the `$timeout` is a mocked service object provided by `ngMock` in your unit test.

Comment: Thanks - I tried just this. I added `$timeout.flush(); expect($timeout.verifyNoPendingTasks()).not.toThrow()` after `dashboard.elements = ...`, but I received the following error: `No more request expected`, and the test quit. Is that expected?

Comment: Above error could be due to an empty $http request queue. If you are making any http request, you may need to look at https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$httpBackend

Comment: Also, I've updated my answer with a link to CodePen code snippet. This code snippet has a unit test for a controller that updates a $scope variable using $timeout service.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to spy on $timeout, you'll need to actually [replace it](https://flexdiary.blogspot.com/2016/09/spying-on-angularjs-services-that-are_89.html) in a module.decorator call with a spy. But you may want to ask yourself if it truly makes sense to micromanage the internals of your directive to that extent.